# Question about limit involving exp

Tags: calculus, limits

I came across the following passage that I'm a bit confused about:

"In the limit of large $n$,

$$\exp(-\frac{c^x}{n})$$

will tend to zero only if $c^x$ grows faster than $n$, meaning that our smallest value of $x$ is the value such that
$$c^x=an^{1 +\varepsilon}$$

with $a$ constant and $\varepsilon \to 0$ from above"

Can someone help me understand the last portion of this?

Specifically, where are we getting $an^{1+\varepsilon}$, why do we need the constants $a$ and $\varepsilon$, and why do we need $\varepsilon\to 0$ from above?

Comment: Please don't post images or links to equations.  Instead typeset them in *MathJax*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of $c^{x}$ as a function that has to grow faster than $n$, but at the same time we want a "small" function that does the job. To find it, we use that $\frac{c^{x}}{n} \rightarrow \infty$, since we want to out speed $n$ by a short amount, we could model $c^{x}$ as a function of $n$, namely $f(n)$, for which we impose $\frac{f(n)}{n} \rightarrow \infty $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. We can achieve a very low rate of divergence when $f(n) = n^{1 + \varepsilon}$ because $f(n)/n = n^{\varepsilon}$, if we want to make this diverge slowly we just make $\varepsilon$ infinitely small. Finally to get the general result, we can multiply $f(n)$ by any positive constant $a$ and we'll be in the same family of functions as $f(n)$.

I hope this helps you with a little intuition.

Comment: Not true.  $f=n\log(n)$ suffices too and grows more slowly than $n^{1+\varepsilon}$ for all $\varepsilon>9$.

Comment: Right, I was giving an intuition about the result, the OP was asking for. I guess it's correct if I change smallest by small.

Comment: Indeed.  There is no "smallest" growth rate here.